# Simplify reputation threshold message

Tags: feature-request, user-experience, error-message, protected-questions

I refer to this message:

> Thank you for your interest in this question. Because it has attracted low-quality or spam answers that had to be removed, posting an answer now requires 10 reputation on this site (the association bonus does not count).

Why not simply add the association bonus so the last clause reads "posting an answer requires 110 reputation on this site"?

Answer (score 12):

Because users who don't have the association bonus but have at least 10 rep on the site can answer protected questions.

Comment: Don't you need to associate with the site in the first place in order to answer questions?

Comment: "Associate with" and "have an account on" are not the same thing. You need to have an account to answer questions, but you don't need to have earned the association bonus, which happens when you have 200 rep on any site.

Comment: @pppery possibly adding a sentence like "it's possible to create an account on other stacks without having an SO account precendently" might clear some confusion Chuck seem to have?